# Could one still learn a good policy by doing a backprop every fixed number of steps within an episode?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, policy-gradients

Waiting an entire episode before doing a backprop can build up a very large computational graph, which is a burden on memory. Could one still learn a good policy by doing a backprop every fixed number of steps *within* an episode? E.g. backprop every 500 steps. Is there any literature about this that I can check out?

Comment: in One-step actor-critic, the update rule is performed after every step using the td error. might want to check that our

Comment: @HadarSharvit you might as well write this an answer

Answer (score 1):

In [One-Step Actor-Critic](https://marcinbogdanski.github.io/rl-sketchpad/RL_An_Introduction_2018/1305a_One_Step_Actor_Critic.html), the update rule is performed after every step using the TD error. might want to check that out